# How to install Windows 7 on formatted drives?

Tags: windows, boot, installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on a formatted drive from DVD, but I always get an error which says that the drive does not have bootmgr:

> BOOTMGR is missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

When I set the BIOS to boot from the DVD drive, nothing happens.

What should I do to boot Windows 7 from DVD?

Answer (score 2):

It can happen that your MBR will be corrupted/damaged after a cold-start of your PC and then you need to know how to fix the MBR in Windows 7? Usually, you will encounter the dreaded error message: “Operating System not found“. There’s a really easy command that can be executed via the command line utility to fix it. But how to access the command line tool without operating system in the first place?

**Fix MBR – Operating system not found**

1. Start PC, Insert Windows 7 DVD and hit a key when asked to. You may have to change your boot order to boot from DVD!
2. Click on “Repair your computer“:
   [image]
3. The installer will scan your PC for previous Windows installations:
   [image]
   [image]
4. Click on Command Prompt
   [image]
5. Enter the following command on one line:

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

**Fix MBR (Operating system found/logged on)**

1. On boot up press F8 and select “Repair your computer”.
2. Next, Windows 7 will automatically search for errors. Let it check for errors and when it’s done close the window. At the bottom you will see the “Command Prompt” tool. Click on it.
3. Enter the command

> bootrec.exe /fixmbr

Comment: thnx for effort